# Проблема с изменением данных в базе данных

Tags: php, html, mysql

Получаю данные из базы данных, они вносятся в поля - https://i.stack.imgur.com/PZiXG.png

Нажимаю на кнопку "Сохранить" выскакивает ошибка :

> Ошибка ввода в базу данныхYou have an error in your SQL syntax; check
>   the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right
>   syntax to use near 'Коннор, известный как Bones — парень, который ' at
>   line 1

Метод который выполняет эти операции (взятие данных и изменение данных):

```
protected function obr(){

        if (!empty($_FILES['img_src']['tmp_name']))
            if (!move_uploaded_file($_FILES['img_src']['tmp_name'],'img/'.$_FILES['img_src']['name'])){
                exit("Не удалось загрузить изображение");
        }

        $img_src = 'img/'.$_FILES['img_src']['name'];

        $id = $_POST['id'];
        $title = $_POST['title'];
        $date = date("Y-m-d", time());
        $discription = $_POST['discription'];
        $text = $_POST['text'];
        $cat = $_POST['cat'];

        if (empty($title) || empty($text) || empty($discription)){
            exit("Не заполненны обязательные поля");
        }

    $query = "UPDATE statii SET title='$title',img_src='$img_src',date='$date',text='$text',discription='$discription',cat='$cat' WHERE id='$id'";

        if(!mysql_query($query)){
            exit("Ошибка ввода в базу данных".mysql_error());    
        }else{
            $_SESSION['res'] = "Изменения внесены успешно";
            header("Location:?option=admin");
            exit();
        }    
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Самый простой выход

```
$id = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['id']);
$title = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['title']);
$date = date("Y-m-d", time());
$discription = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['discription']);
$text = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['text']);
$cat = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['cat']);
```